# Magento2: Unassigned category from product

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

I am trying to make script to unassign category from product while save or update product. but its not working properly.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Increase memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';


$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


$appState = $obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');


$pid = 528;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
$_product->setCategoryIds('')->save();
```

Does anyone know another way for it? except direct query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove a product from a category:

If you want to ***remove a product from a category*** then you can use below solution:

> ```
> $categoryId = 12 ; // Category id 
> $pid = 150; // Product Id
> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
> $_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
> $CategoryLinkRepository =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface');
> $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryId, $productSku);
> ```

### Remove all  categories from a product:

Then try this:

```
$pid = 150; // Product Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
$CategoryLinkRepository =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface');
$productSku = $_product->getSku();

// all catgeories of a category
$currentCategories  = $_product->getCategoryIds();
  foreach ($currentCategories as $categoryId) {
            $CategoryLinkRepository ->deleteByIds($categoryId, $productSku);
 }
// reindex a product in magento                 

$productCategoryIndexer = $objectManager
                            ->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')
                            ->get(Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category::INDEXER_ID);              
$productCategoryIndexer->reindexRow($_product->getId());
```

Comment: How can i do it by CSV in Multi store

Comment: While trying to unassigned the categories mannually ,when product edit, it is not working

Comment: It worked for 1-2 products but after that, It started to give this error `Unable to serialize value`

Comment: I tried second scripts and it's worked, thanks!