# Unassigned category from product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category

I have tried following code but does't work

```
$all_categoty=$_product->getCategoryIds();
   $CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository'); 
               foreach($all_categoty as $cat){
                           if($cat=="15"){
                                                continue;
                           }
$CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($cat ,$_product->getSku());
}
```

**Then try with reindexing but doesn't remove the category**

```
$productCategoryIndexer = $objectManager ->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')
  ->get(Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category::INDEXER_ID);
$productCategoryIndexer->reindexRow($_product->getId());
```

Comment: Code seems code ok.only need to add try and catch `try{

}catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException $e)
{
    
}catch (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException $e )
{
    
}`

Comment: check `getCategoryIds` value.i guess that have issue only with it

Comment: `getCategoryIds` its working fine

Comment: After run of `$CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($cat ,$_product->getSku());` .Please do indexing from admin and see what  happen?

Comment: in product edit page in admin show category as it is.

Comment: It is mean `deleteByIds($cat ,$_product->getSku());` code is not woking. Please check magento errors log

Comment: i give following error
Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Flat::saveAttribute()

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Flat::saveAttribute() in /magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php:66`

Answer (score 1):

please check this [Magento2: Unassigned category from product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197752/magento2-unassigned-category-from-product) and if your are updating a product a the same time is not gonna work

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10555

Answer (score 0):

you're forgot to save category repository after modify:

```
$CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($cat ,$_product->getSku());
$CategoryLinkRepository->save($category);
```

Also I recommend didn't use "magic numbers" like this one:

```
if($cat=="15"){
              continue;
}
```

This is a bad practice, because categories id's may be changed when database is moved, plus when you or other developer will working with that code is remember why category id=15 must be skipped aren't easy.

Comment: any other idea to skip this category??

Comment: `$CategoryLinkRepository->save($category); 
`

which $category i have passed??